# Why Is A FilePath Item With ~$ Added To ListBox

Tags: vb.net, listboxitem

I am adding file paths from a folder to a List Box which are then opened as text in a Rich Text Box. I have used the same syntax as the code below for achieving the same purpose in another List Box and it works just fine. But, in the current example, I have two files in the default MyProjects folder (i.e. default folder is created by my app), but when I add the file paths from the folder as items to the List Box, I get a third item with ~$ in the file path? This item is obviously some kind of repetition of the first file path in the list? The two files in the default folder are also created by my app so, if this is a file access issue, I don't understand why I wouldn't have access to a file created by my app? Can anyone give me a clue what's happening here?

**What I have Tried:**

I have tried debugging to check where the extra file path is coming from. As far as I can tell, it is being created when I add the file paths to the List Box? i.e. commenting out the code for adding the items to the List Box stops all items being added, but doesn't tell me where this extra item is coming from?

**The "Extra Item" Issue:**

System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+ObjectCollectionC:\Users\username\Documents\MySolution\MyProjects\RTFdoc.rtf
C:\Users\username\Documents\MySolution\MyProjects\Testdoc.rtf
C:\Users\username\Documents\MySolution\MyProjects~$Fdoc.rtf

**The Code:**

```
lbxName.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\" + username + "\Documents\MySolution\MyProjects"))
lbxName.SelectedIndex = 0
```

**Code For Loading:**

```
For Each item In lbxName.SelectedItems
    RTB.LoadFile(lbxName.SelectedItem, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
Next
```

Comment: It's simply giving you files that exist.  If you don't want "extra" file, delete it.  Figure out why it is being produced in the first place and prevent that.  The `GetFiles()` call isn't failing here...

Comment: This file is (pretty probably)  a hidden file used by the editor you had used to modify or create that .rtf. This file contains information about which user has the file open and settings associated with SO infos. Enable hidden files visualisation (in Folder Option) to see if is that, and/or open/close properly by editor which had created these or delete manually.

Comment: Hi Idle_Mind, the reason I'm asking the question is because after debugging and looking for possible solutions within my code, I couldn't "figure out why..." the extra file is being produced! As you will see in my reply to G3nt_M3caj, the file is not a hidden file in file explorer!

Comment: "I am adding file paths from a folder to a List Box which are then opened as text in a Rich Text Box."  How are you loading the files into the RicthTextBox?  I've never actually looked, does .Net's [RichTextBox.LoadFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.loadfile?view=netcore-3.1) create the temp file?

Comment: Hi G3nt_M3caj, I enabled hidden files in FE, but the file doesn't appear in the folder. I guess it may be a temp file of some kind being generated when adding items to the list box? However, although I can see this file path as a third item in the list box and got the file path in debugging (i.e. as per my example above), I have no idea how to debug to discover the origin of the extra file or how to prevent the file from being created? I generate RTF Markup from Rich Text Box, save to an .rtf file, open the file as RTF Markup and convert back to produce the RTB content, i.e. an image and text.

Comment: @JohnMichaelWilkinson If you are doing that (open those files) during elaboration by a RichtextboxControl, yes, it’s possible is a temp file created by RichTextBoxControl. I'll post an answer try to avoid those files

Comment: Hi Idle Mind, yeah I'm using LoadFile() as a RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText... I'll add the code above...

Comment: Here are some debugging tips: Try logging values like the fileInfo.Attributes and checking if there is any difference from the files that you want in the listbox. You can also try deleting the folder and recreating it. Finally, Try removing all code that saves or creates rtf files.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce the error in the following code.

```
Private Sub FillListBox()
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\" & username & "\Documents\MySolution\MyProjects"))
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FillListBox()
End Sub
```

Please read the comments in the following code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each item In ListBox1.SelectedItems
        'The following will overwrite the contents of the RichTextBox on each iteration
        'This overload of LoadFile will only handle .rtf files
        RichTextBox1.LoadFile(item.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

I suggest you set the `SelectionMode` property to `One` in the designer and do the following.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    RichTextBox1.LoadFile(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use as follows:

```
Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\" & username & "\Documents\MySolution\MyProjects").Where(Function(f)
Return New IO.FileInfo(f).Attributes & IO.FileAttributes.Hidden & IO.FileAttributes.System = 0
```

Comment: Hey G3nt_M3caj, tried that, but didn't get any results? Also, I tried removing the files I had in the default MyProjects folder and created new ones using my app. But, the previous file path still appears (i.e. C:\Users\username\Documents\MySolution\MyProjects~$Fdoc.rtf) even though this file is no longer in the folder??? So, I guess the issue is not being caused by the files themselves? The new files didn't create a similar file path?

Comment: When I use that path to open the file, it throws an exception: " File format is not valid."